# What method to use for conditional density querying

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, conditional-probability, gan

I have a dataset of 3d poses each represented by 40 points (all relative to the central point). So my data has dimensionality 120. What is needed is to learn how build realistic pose, when positions of some nodes are known. Some kind of conditional distribution querying. I've been trying solve this problem with GAN, but to train such networks is quite problematic. So the question is, which is the best way to solve this problem? May be some kind of gaussian kernel density estimation?  Or perhaps just spend more time fine-tuning GAN?